# Setting up tabs on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to setup the tabs a React component in the parent component states, something like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import Component1 from '../myChildComponents/Component1';
import Component2 from '../myChildComponents/Component2';
import Component3 from '../myChildComponents/Component3';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabs: [
        {id: '1', text: 'Tab 1', component: Component1},
        {id: '2', text: 'Tab 2', component: Component2},
        {id: '3', text: 'Tab 3', component: Component3},
      ]
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <!-- All the other stuff goes here, like the tabs headers -->
      <TabContent>
      {
        this.state.tabs.map((t, i) => 
          <TabPane key={i} tabId={t.tabId}>
            <t.component {...this.props.data}>
          </TabPane>
        )
      }
      </TabContent>
    )
  }
}
```

Can something like this be achieved? I already tried using the `React.createComponent` function, but this worked

Edit1: Updated to reflect current test implementation, still seeing the following message on the console

> Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render metho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can use a component like that.

```
 render() {
    return (
      <!-- All the other stuff goes here, like the tabs headers -->
      <TabContent>
      {
        this.state.tabs.map((t, i) => 
          <TabPane key={i} tabId={t.tabId}>
            <t.component {...t.data}/>
          </TabPane>
        )
      }
      </TabContent>
    )
  }
```

Only thing you need to change is:

- your object key is `component`; lower case
- you need to set the props by using the spread operator on the `t.data` object: `{...t.data}`

Comment: Well, I tried to do so, with curly brackets, sorrounding the expected component to be renderes, I got `Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method`

Comment: And without the curly backet (`{id: '1', text: 'Tab 1', component: component1, data: {props.data1}}`) got `Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method`

Comment: @CJLopez remove the curly braces around `{props.data1}`, data2 and data3 etc

Comment: it should be `{id: '1', text: 'Tab 1', component: {component1}, data: props.data1}`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using in the end, a property set in the states, I'm passing directly the data from the props, and just grab what I need in the child component `<t.component {...this.props.data}/>`

Comment: Aaaaand... just out of the blue, it started working as you mentioned. Marked your answer as the correct one. Thanks!